# Rotate a UIImageView according to UIWindow Orientations?

Tags: ios4, uiimageview, image-rotation

I have a UIImageView in bottom side of UIWindow. I want it to always display it in bottom side whatever the orientation is, but having trouble implementing it. Any Solution for this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"rotate");

if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)){
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate; 

    // Rotate 90 degrees to hide it off screen
    CGAffineTransform rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(rotationTransform,DegreesToRadians(0));
    delegate.imgV.transform = rotationTransform;

}
else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)){
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate; 

    // Rotate 90 degrees to hide it off screen
    CGAffineTransform rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(rotationTransform,DegreesToRadians(90));
    delegate.imgV.transform = rotationTransform;

}
```

**Enjoy :-)**

Comment: DegreesToRadians is define value. like-- #define DegreesToRadians(x) (M_PI * (x) / 180.0)

Comment: I have added #define also but it's not working see screenshot

Comment: once try to change your image view frame size when device is orientated.

Comment: I think window orientation is always portrait. you should check the uidevice orientation and set the imageview transformation.